Conditional formatting depending on two cells
I am making a google sheet to keep track of when an item goes for repair,
However this would require setting it to every cell where that would be able to happen so 52*52,
So I’m looking to see if anyone has a better solution,
I am more than happy to share an example if needed
This is the current formula which I’ve got which is the following =IF(AND(J2=1,L1=”WK1”)True,False)
Example Link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mILCI2-Ev2RiTKfL0kG92jZMQmy1jCh6I2_WfH-pDxA/edit?usp=sharing


Here's one approach you may test out:
=$C4=--regexextract(D$3,"\d+")



Thank you very much! That is perfect and exactly what I was looking for! I can't upvote the answer but again thanks!

Using MAP for Dynamic Spilling the Formula
There are plenty of methods to Dynamically Spill a formula to a certain Range.
As what you have shared the formula which works and, I have based my sample dataset along with what your requirements are and created a formula around that.
Try this:
=MAP(J2:J16,L1:L15, LAMBDA(x,y, IF((x=1)*(y="WK1"),TRUE,FALSE)))

Sample Output:

Reference:
MAP
Note: Due to limited information about your dataset, this may not be perfectly fit with your current project right away. Feel free to ask questions for clarification if you encounter any issues along the way.

I will try this now, and get back to you if not, I will also link the dummy dataset ive got which will hopefully help!

I tried it, however I am not sure if I am not using it correctly, so I've added the link to the original post to a Dummy Sheet, In sheet 1 is there I have added the way I do it, and then sheet 2, is using your formula.
If you look at sheet 1, and change the due date (Column C) it automatically highlights the cell, which is more or less what I want but without having to do it 52 times per item, which will have 52, instead of the two I've put for the dummy test!
Thanks for your help!
